# Can sector size of USB flash drive be changed?

Tags: c, embedded, usb

i know the cluster size of a USB flash drive can be changed , can we change the sector size too ??

Comment: What do you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

Sector size isn't a configurable parameter in ATA/SATA/SCSI/etc devices and, from my experience, USB flash drives implement one of these protocols. The sector size *is* reported by the device itself but, even if you could set it to something other than 512, you would likely run into a latent bug somewhere in a driver or file system package that assumed a sector size of 512.

There are real reasons for using a sector size like 512, for example, addressing of larger sectors can be done more quickly and efficiently (not just in time but in size/space as well). Throughput to these devices is also better with something like 512. Consider that, if you *could* set sector size to something like 16-bytes, you might have less wasted space with 16-byte sectors compared to having a number of half-full 512-byte sectors, but your throughput to the device would probably be worse. In fact, writing a single 16-byte sector would only be slightly faster than writing a single 512-byte sector. On the other hand, writing 32 16-byte sectors (to write a total of 512 bytes) would likely take longer than writing a single 512 byte sector simply due to the overhead associated with transferring multiple sectors.

I would suggest you buy a larger USB flash drive if you are worried about wasting space with 512-byte sectors.